# Pandas isin equivalent for float or int

Tags: python, pandas, integer, isin

I have a dataframe with column A populated with numbers 1-9. I want to filter just on numbers 2 and 3. isin does not work for float dtypes. Is there an alternative?

something similar to:

```
df=df.loc[df['ColA'].isin([2,3])]
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if need test `2.0, 3.0, 2, 3` your solution working well.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [2.0, 6, -1, 3.0]})
print (df.loc[df['ColA'].isin([2,3])])
   ColA
0   2.0
3   3.0
```

If need convert floats to integers:

```
df=df.loc[df['ColA'].astype(int).isin([2,3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try `pd.to_numeric` to convert `float` to `int`:

```
df = df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['ColA'], downcast=int).isin([2, 3])]
```

Comment: Are you sure? can you expalin more?

Comment: `Or you could try pd.to_numeric to convert float to int` ? It is wrong